# cargar solo un datos especifico de mi base de datos con axios - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

como hago para extraer solo un dato de la base de datos, he logrado que haga un .map pero necesito que solo me muestre un dato especifico para poder trabajar con el, he intentado sacar un valor de mi base de datos pero no he podido , lo que necesito es poder extraer un valor puntual de mi base de datos, lo  he intentado pero todavia no lo he logrado.

**lo que necesito es que solo me cargue el campo color que aparece en la ruta.**

```js
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

function Pruebas() {

 const baseUrlAd="https://www.deportes.controlsas.com/apiPlooy/Solicitar_empresa/" 
 const [data, setData]=useState([]);

 //cargar mostrar
 const peticionGet =async() =>{
  await axios.get(baseUrlAd)
  .then(response=>{
   setData(response.data);
  console.log(response.data); 
  }).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error);
  })

}

useEffect(()=>{
    
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    peticionGet();  
   }, 3000);
 return () => setInterval(interval);
 },[])

  return (
    <div>

{
       global.one = data.map(item => (
           <h6>{item.color}</h6>
        ))
       
      }
          
    </div>
  )
}

export default Pruebas
```

Comment: Estas solicitando datos al `endpoint` `https://www.deportes.controlsas.com/apiPlooy/Solicitar_empresa/` eso por lo que se ve en el código regresa un array de objetos, donde existe una propiedad `color` por cada elemento. Si quieres solo un dato en especifico, entonces debes revisar si tienes un `endpoint` que te regrese ese dato en especifico y hacer la consulta ahi, de otra forma si el dato en especifico que necesitas ya viene en el endpoint que estas usando, entonces solo te queda filtrar y asignar a un estado. ¿Puedes explicar un poco más los detalles? Saludos

Comment: lo que necesito es que solo me cargue el campo color que aparece en la ruta .

Comment: si tu data trae muchos datos podrías usar el [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), algo así como `global.one = data.find((e) => e.id === 1)?.color;`, por que el map te regresa el campo que tu le indicas pero en un array.

Comment: como hago para sacar ese valor "color" del .map y pasarlo a una variable

Comment: si regresas solo el color en el map, solo accede a el primer ítem de tu array `data.map((e) => e.color)[0];`

Comment: lo que necesito es que style={{ backgroundColor: data.map((e) => e.color)[0]; }}  ya que carga desde la base  de datos el codigo del color pero no me funciona..

Comment: aqui estructure mejor la pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495095/no-me-carga-el-registro-puntual-con-axios-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

import React, {} from 'react';

export const App = () => {
const fetchData = async() => {
const baseUrlAd="https://www.deportes.controlsas.com/apiPlooy/Solicitar_empresa/" ;
fetch(baseUrlAd).then(value => console.log(value))
}
fetchData()

return (

{

```
    }
</div>
```

)
}

no se trabajar con axios pero hice una peticion a esa api y no devuelve nada de colors[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]