# no me carga el registro puntual con axios - reactjs

Tags: php, reactjs

No he podido que cargue el registro que tengo en la ruta con axios para que me lo cargue en mi `<div>`, mi endospoint lo tengo en php y no se si tenga algo mal configurado con mi select, he intentado de muchas formas pero no lo he logrado, se que el problema puede estar en mi php pero no se como resolverlo.

El problema es que no me reconoce  mi consulta `https://www.deportes.controlsas.com/apiPlooy/Solicitar_empresa/#FF8933d` ya que si coloco otra consulta por ejemplo  `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto` y utilizo name en vez de color y funciona, no se que debo cambiar en mi consulta en mi php

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const App = (_) => {
  const [color, setName] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://www.deportes.controlsas.com/apiPlooy/Solicitar_empresa/#FF8933d`)
      .then((res) => {
        setName(res.data.color);
      })
  }, []);


  return <div>{color}</div>;
};
export default App;
```

//PHP

```js
<?php

include '../bd/global.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
    if(true){
        $query="select color from datos_torneo where color ='#FF8933'";
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
        echo json_encode($resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }else{
        $query="select color from datos_torneo where color = color'#FF8933'";
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
        echo json_encode($resultado->fetchAll()); 
    }
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    exit();
}



header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");


?>
```

Comment: ¿Esta llegando el valor que necesitas en `res.data.name`? Puedes dar un `console.log(res.data.name)` dentro de la función `then` para verificar.

Comment: me aparece undefine

Comment: pon un console.log de res

Comment: bien, entonces no hay una propiedad `name` en la respuesta `res.data`, ese es el origen del problema, ahora da un `console.log(res.data)` y revisa cual es el nombre del parámetro del cual necesitas extraer el dato.

Comment: el problema esta es https://www.deportes.controlsas.com/apiPlooy/Solicitar_empresa/#FF8933d ya que si coloco otra ruta por ejemplo https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto funciona, osea que debo correguir mi php pero no se que debo cambiar en mi consulta..

Comment: El error debe ser que tu petición te regresa el json como string, entonces deberías pasearlo a  un objeto algo así como `var datos = JSON.parse(res.data)`, antes de tomar el color y después si usar el objeto parseado y acceder a la propiedad `datos.color`

Comment: como quedaria en el codigo? por que no me funciona

Comment: acabo de copiar tu código y de hecho así como lo tienes me funciona, https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-wozniak-04cj7?file=/src/App.js